# I am getting issue in case sensitive in npm. componenct name must start with capital letter, but same code is working in other PC

Tags: reactjs, npm, components

> Line 144:19:  React Hook "useContext" is called in function "canViewMenuGroup" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use"  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
>
> Line 157:19:  React Hook "useContext" is called in function "canViewMenuItem" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use"   react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Is there any package which I need to install to disable to check case sensitivity?

Comment: Have you checked the npm and node version in both pc ?

Comment: yes both pc has same version of npm and node.